# How to get baseURI for NFTs in IPFS using Fleek?

Tags: solidity, nft, ipfs

I have been trying to use Fleek to host my NFTs. But the folder link they are providing, which I wants to use as baseURI in my contract, is using their own storage API, rather an IPFS link. Is there any way to get the folder IPFS link rather than the storage API link?

Answer (score 0):

On the *Storage* tab of the Fleek dashboard, find the folder you want the IPFS CID for. Then click *Verify on IPFS*, which will open the folder up on Fleek's IPFS gateway.

[image: Fleek storage dashboard]

Copy the [IPFS CID](https://docs.ipfs.io/concepts/content-addressing/#identifier-formats) from the link and resolve it using a gateway of your choice. The CID will usually look like a long blob of characters (alphanumeric) and start with `Qm`.

For example, in the link `https://ipfs.fleek.co/ipfs/QmTecfbJp9xpxoGur23fBEUYQCta7MCKygGyCMa4YQcp1D` the CID would be `QmTecfbJp9xpxoGur23fBEUYQCta7MCKygGyCMa4YQcp1D`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have been trying this but the CID that is opening is only showing 1 file, .keep, rather than all the files present in the folder. Any solution to that?

Comment: I would reach out to Fleek. My best guess is that they only upload the files to IPFS periodically